# Regular expression within a MS-Word Macro

Tags: regex, vba, ms-word

There's something wrong with my regular expression in a MS-Word 2019 Macro, but when I do check it in Notepad++, it works just fine. Are there any limitations in VBA or is it my regex ? Thanks

The text that I'm parsing is given below. In it, I want to identify the string **any_filename.ext**, based on the regex :

- the searched pattern is at the beginning of one line => **^**
- the searched pattern is followed by the **$£** and an EOL => **.+£\$$**

Thus the regexp **^.+£\$$**

```vba
Set regExp = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")

' Search for a string starting at he beginning of a line 
' and ending with £$ followed by a carriage return.
With regExp
    .Pattern = "^.+£\$$"  

    .Global = False         
    .IgnoreCase = True      
    .MultiLine = False      
End With

If regExp.test(docWork.Range.text) Then
     Set allMatches = regExp.Execute(docWork.Range.text)
     For Each aMatch In allMatches
        DebugPrint ("Match.Value : " + aMatch.Value)
     Next
End If
```

The content of docWork.Range.Text is :

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
any_filename.ext£$
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, 
sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore 
magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation
ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. 
Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse 
cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint 
occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia 
deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it. 
It should be as this to search throught multiple lines text. 
regExp.MultiLine = True

Comment: When answering yoru own question, please accept the answer with the green checkmark on the left so that the question does not remain open.